# Download file on Client Side from S3 Signed Url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios, fetch

I have currently implemented the following:

1. Client Clicks a button to download the CSV (GET Request to Backend).
2. Backend Generates the CSV, uploads it to S3.
3. Backend gets the signed url using `getSignedUrl()` method of S3 and sends it in response to the GET Request.
4. On Dashboard, call the signed url using `fetch(signedUrl)` and use `js-file-download` npm package to download the file on client side.

S3 bucket is Private.

**The Issue:**
Getting CORS on `Step 4` calling the signedUrl using `fetch`. How to avoid CORS?
Does the bucket need to be configured in a some way, or `fetch` shouldn't be used?

Tried to follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html#cors-example-1, but no luck.

Should I use axios with some settings, if that can work?

Comment: Does your bucket have a CORS configuration? Does your bucket name include a hyphen?

Comment: No, I havent setup CORS configuration for Bucket. And no, Bucket name doesnt have hyphen.

Comment: @jarmod, thank you, i added the CORS Config and now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on jarmod's comment i found the following link. I added the CORS Configuration as to my bucket.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]
```

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-configure-cors/